# How to display specific row in vuejs api

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just want to ask how to display/fetch data from API to my textbox
when you click the edit button in a specific row table. It will display it's own id and other details. I'm so sorry to post my code like this, I don't know how to do it because it gives me errors.

Raw Code **:**

```
data : {
  students : []
}
methods: {
  async editStudents(edit) {
    let id = "621ecc95817b5aeb5783aebe"
    let a = await 
    this.$axios.get(`https://api.qa.sampleapi.com/students/${id}`)
    console.log(a.data.data)
}
```

It will give me that specific item but how to do it with a for loop.

Sample code **:**

```
editStudent(edit) {
  let studentid = id
  let a = await 
  this.$axios.get(`https://api.qa.sampleapi.com/students/${studentid}`)
  for(let i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
    if(edit.studentid === this.students[i].studentid) {
      this.textbox1 = this.students[i].studentid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Few clarifications :

 - Why are you trying to fetch the student id again as you already have that id ?
 - As you are fetching the details for a particular student from an API. Why are you comparing ? It could be simple, You can pass the student id (which you get on edit button click) in the API call and get the details for that particular student.

Comment: Im so sorry sir I just don't really know how to get specific id on every row. I already fetch all the data from the API but I don't know how to get specific id in every row using for loop.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I came up with below solution. Please let me know if it works as per your requirement or not.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    students: [{
        id: 1,
      name: 'Student 1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
      name: 'Student 2'    
    }, {
        id: 3,
      name: 'Student 3'   
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    editStudent(id) {
        console.log(id); // You will get the student ID here
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="list">
    <li v-for="student in students" :key="student.id">
      {{ student.name }}
      <button @click="editStudent(student.id)">Edit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```